# Call a method of an object whose name is stored in a variable - PHP

Tags: php

This question may sound stupid, but I want this to work. I've got this code:

```
$data['method'] = 'get';
$this->app->$data['method']();
```

How can I replace `$data['method']` with `get` but no string. I've tried this, but no luck.

```
$this->app->{$data['method']}();
```

Any idea?

Comment: [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

function example(){
 echo "hello";
}
$function = "example";
$function(); // will run the function "example" and show "Hello".

Comment: Interestingly I also tried what you tried and _yes_ luck.

Comment: my bad. I'm sorry guys. the last code does work. a little drunk last night and didn't realize that I had the wrong piece in my editor while wrote the right one here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last code you posted should work, if you're using **PHP 5.4.0 and higher**.

```
<?php

class A {
    public function foo() {
        echo "yes!";
    }
}

class B {
    public function run() {

        $this->a = new A;

        $data = [];
        $data['method'] = "foo";        
        $this->a->{$data['method']}();        

    }
}

$b = new B;
$b->run();
// Prints "yes!"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
call_user_func(array($this->app, $data['method']));
```

good luck.